Raspberry Pi stuck after "Started login service"
I've just restored the ext4 partition of my SD card via e2fsck. Everything goes fine and now I've no more the ext4-fs error on boot.
Unfortunatelly now I cannot login because on the startup the Raspberry 3B+ hangs on "Started login service" and I cannot type anything in.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Restore from your backup.

Any chance to solve in another way?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
